# SignalR hangs on IIS - when more than 2 Clients

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, signalr, signalr.client

I am facing a strange behaviour of SignalR. When I run my application from Visual Studio 2013 everything works fine and I can connect as many clients as I want (or at least a reasonable number). Now, when I move my app to IIS it works fine as long as I have two clients (I open IE, Firefox and Chrome as 3 Clients). When I add a third client, it stops working. I can send messages from every client, but the others one dont get them. Now, when I refresh the third client, or make another request, all the pending messages are being sent. Its like they are stuck somewhere and waiting to be flushed. Or when I close the third client, the other two clients work again as expected

I found this [SignalR connection hangs, calls client ~30 seconds later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12887976/signalr-connection-hangs-calls-client-30-seconds-later) answer, seems as the same problem, but didnt resolve my problem (I am using Integrated Pipeline not Classic)

I also tried setting the max number of clients, but that cant be the problem, bcz then it wouldnt work inside Visual Studio too.

Does anybody has a clue what else I could try ?

Edit: Tried with the project form Microsoft [SignalR For Starters](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/SignalR-Getting-Started-b9d18aa9) and same behaviour. Inside visual Studio I can connect as many chat clients as I want, but inside IIS after 2 of them I dont receive anything

Comment: This question has the awnser: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32153313/signalr-fails-with-more-than-2-connections